# Online backups with VENDOR library: what should be set for ACTIVE LOG PATH?

Tags: backup, db2, transaction-log

My customer is using Veritas NetBackup so we use its library file in the `LOGARCHMETH1` parameter for the VENDOR option. That is for archive logging path.

What path should be set for `ACTIVE LOG PATH` (`LOGPATH`)? Some location on local database storage? Will DB2 then transfer from active to archive logs between those two servers (database and Veritas NetBackup) automatically? Or how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The active log path (database configuration parameter `LOGPATH`) for a database MUST be a locally accessible directory on the database server.  Preferably one with very good read/write performance.  (I'd say it must be a local directory, but technically you *can* specify the path on an NFS mount).

When DB2 fills a transaction log file (and all transactions contained within have been committed), the DB2 log archiver process will copy the file according to what you've set in the `LOGARCHMETH1` and `LOGARCHMETH2` configuration parameters.